# .htaccess rewrite url check if languages is set

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have index.php where it set the language with index.php?lang=de.
English is the default language which I don't need to use index.php?lang=en

When the language is set it use this condition in htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+)/$ /index.php?lang=$1 [L]
```

When the language is not set

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+)$ /index.php?pag=$1 [L]
```

When language and page is set

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+)$ /index.php?lang=$1&pag=$2 [L]
```

When language, page, and sub-page is set

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+)$ /index.php?lang=$1&pag=$2&spag=$3 [L]
```

But I can't access sub-page when the language is not set, when is english it must to be

```
 index.php?pag=services&spag=web_design
 RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+)$ /index.php?pag=$2&spag=$3 [L]
```

Any idea how to make it work?
Also if you have an idea to merge all this line in a single one will be wonderful.

Thanks!

Comment: Is language always 2 in length with both alphabets?

Comment: yes, language always has 2 characters...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand it, someone would access your page in the following format:

```
http://www.mysite.com/LANGUAGE/PAGE/SUBPAGE/
```

Something like:

```
http://www.mysite.com/ENGLISH/events/upcoming
```

would translate to:

```
http://www.mysite.com/index.php?lang=ENGLISH&pag=events&spag=upcoming
```

Which would take them to the *English* version of `Events->Upcoming`?

## Solution

Assuming the above to be correct. The following will work:

```
ReWriteRule ^([\w-]*)/*([\w-]*)/*([\w-]*)/*$ index.php?lang=$1&pag=$2&spag=$3
```

Running `var_dump($_GET)` in `index.php` would then output the following:

```
// http://www.mysite.com/ENGLISH/home/upcoming
array(3) {
  ["lang"]=>
  string(7) "ENGLISH"
  ["pag"]=>
  string(4) "home"
  ["spag"]=>
  string(8) "upcoming"
}
```

If one isn't set then you place it as a zero (or leave it blank if at the end) in the url, like so:

```
http://www.mysite.com/0/home
```

Which would give:

```
array(3) {
  ["lang"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["pag"]=>
  string(4) "home"
  ["spag"]=>
  string(0) ""
}
```

### Example URLs

```
http://www.mysite.com/ENGLISH/news/recent/
http://www.mysite.com/ENGLISH/about/
http://www.mysite.com/ENGLISH/
http://www.mysite.com/0/news/recent/
http://www.mysite.com/0/about/
http://www.mysite.com/0/
```

### Order

You could also change the order... So that language comes last:

```
ReWriteRule ^([\w-]*)/*([\w-]*)/*([\w-]*)/*$ index.php?lang=$3&pag=$1&spag=$2
```

and use URLs like:

```
http://www.mysite.com/news/recent/ENGLISH
http://www.mysite.com/about/history/
http://www.mysite.com/about
```

Comment: I use switch($lang) ... default:
  $lang_file = 'lang.en.php'; and first solution works perfect, because en is default language and I don't need to set $_GET['$lang']... Thanks for solution!

Comment: Okay, erm, I must be missing something haha why is that a problem?

Comment: Just to follow up, you did get this to work for you in the end?

Answer (score 0):

You can use these rules:

```
# just language
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/?$ /index.php?lang=$1 [L,NC,QSA]

# just page
RewriteRule ^([\w-]{3,})/?$ /index.php?pag=$1 [L,QSA]

# lang & page
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/([\w-]+)/?$ /index.php?lang=$1&pag=$2 [L,QSA,NC]

# page & spage
RewriteRule ^([\w-]{3,})/([\w-]+)/?$ /index.php?pag=$1&spag=$2 [L,QSA]

# lang, page & spage
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ /index.php?lang=$1pag=$2&spag=$3 [L,QSA,NC]
```